# Scrolling with jQuery Without using animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrolltop

I'm building a messenger site and want the chat to automatically scroll to the bottom of the chat feed (latest message) when the page is refreshed. I am very new to jQuery and after a bit of searching I have got it to work using `animate()`. This is great when the page first loads too jarring when reloading after a form submit for example.

Is there any way to auto-scroll to the bottom of a container with out animating it?

```
// When page loads
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Load chat. ALSO the chat has to be hard coded in here.
    $('#MessagesContainer').load('/php/chat_ref.php');

    // Scroll to the bottom of the page. ALSO ".height()+500" was a bit of a bodge.
    $("#MessagesContainer").animate({ scrollTop:$('#MessagesContainer').height()+500}, 100);
    return false;
});

// Every 2 seconds.
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function(){
    // Reload the chat.
    $('#MessagesContainer').load('/php/chat_ref.php'); 
    return false;
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Yes, just set `scrollTop()` manually: `$("#MessagesContainer").scrollTop($('#MessagesContainer').height()+500);`. However you should note that AJAX polling is a really bad idea as it does not scale well at all. To build a chat system you should be using Websockets or server sent events.

Answer (score 0):

How about using scrollTop instead of animate?

`$("#MessagesContainer").scrollTop($("#MessagesContainer").height());`

Comment: How about: `$("#MessagesContainer").scrollTop($("#MessagesContainer")[0].scrollHeight);`

If not could you post a code snippet or something on http://jsfiddle.net and mock the message loading? It'll be easier to help that way.